# MATLAB ReliefF Output

Tags: matlab, feature-selection

The outputs of the MATLAB feature selection algorithm reliefF are RANKED and WEIGHTS.

http://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/relieff.html

How are the two outputs related?

Comment: what is exactly unclear when you read the documentation?

Comment: From the documentation, `ranked =

     4     3     1     2


weight =

    0.1399    0.1226    0.3590    0.3754

The fourth predictor is the most important, and the second predictor is the least important. `How are the ranks and weights related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> RANKED are indices of columns in X ordered by attribute importance, meaning RANKED(1) is the index of the most important predictor. WEIGHT are attribute weights ranging from -1 to 1 with large positive weights assigned to important attributes.

So `relieff` doesn't just give you a list of which predictors are most important, it also gives you a list of weights that give you an idea of how important the predictors are.  `WEIGHT(4)`, for example, is the weight of the fourth predictor.  `WEIGHT(RANKED)` will return an ordered list of weights by rank (highest to lowest).

You will note that the weight values for predictors 4 & 3 in this case are actually relatively close. This might indicate that although for this particular set of data the 4th predictor appears to be ranked first, the 4th and 3rd predictors are both important and given a different set of data the ranking could change.

For example, the `fisheriris` data set contains 150 measurements of the four predictors. If we take only two-thirds of them we can get a different result:

```
load fisheriris
[ranked,weight] = relieff(meas(1:100,:),species(1:100),10)
```

This gives us:

```
ranked = 3 4 2 1 weight = 0.1574 0.2265 0.5431 0.4981
```

There are three academic papers referenced [in the documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/relieff.html) on `relieff`. If you really want to understand the details of what it's doing, you should try getting hold of those.